# .htaccess to protect the folders of my website

Tags: .htaccess

I want to give a 301 error when some people try to access for example

http://www.mypage.com/images

or another folder.

Comment: 301 is not an error, it's a permanent redirect. What is the other folder?

Comment: Be aware that if you 'protect' your folders with a permanent redirect, none of the contents will be available. In your example, if you're expecting to serve your site's image files from the `/images` directory, none of them will display.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to redirect a user to the home page if they try to access the certain folders? One way to do this would be to redirect based on the user trying to access a file or directory that doesn't exist. In order for this to work, you can't have anything that is in the DocumentIndex (index.html, index,html, index.php, etc) in your folder. This would go in an .htaccess file that has to be placed in each of the folders you want to "protect".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R]
```